# Joining curved paths to node anchors in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to join to two nodes together following the [simple flow chart](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/) example. I would like to join two blocks with curved arrows that begin and end in the same places on both blocks (or close enough). Instead, I get weird second arrow heads on the original attachment points. I have tried to change the in and out angles but it does not seem to help...

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,arrows}   
\makeatother
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!50!black!20, 
text width=2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2cm, minimum    width=4cm]
\tikzstyle{sblock} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!50!black!20, 
text width=2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2cm, minimum     width=2cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
 % This is the "base case"
   \node [block] at (6,7) (A) {A};  
   \node [sblock] at (1,6) (B) {B};   
   \path [line,thick] (B) edge [ bend right] node {} (A);
   \path [line,thick] (A) edge [bend right] node {} (B);

% This is closer to what I want, but a mess...
   \node [block] at (6,3) (C) {C};  
   \node [sblock] at (1,2) (D) {D};   
   \path [line,thick] (C.west) edge [bend right] node {} (D.east);
   \path [line,thick] (D.east) edge [bend right] node {} (C.west);   

 % No better
   \node [block] at (6,-1) (E) {E};  
   \node [sblock] at (1,-2) (F) {F};   
   \path [line,thick] (E.west) edge [bend right =60] node {} (F.east);
   \path [line,thick] (F.east) edge [bend right=60] node {} (E.west);   
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Silly output]

As you can see, there is a second arrowhead on the lower block (there is one on the upper block too, it is just obscured). Basically I want the arrows to start on the west/east anchor point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to use a `to` path, e.g.

```
\path [line,thick] (E.west) to[out=180,in=60] (F.east);
```

You can also use `edge`, but in that case you need to specify the arrow tip for only the `edge`, not the entire `path`, e.g.

```
\path [thick] (C.west) edge [line,bend left] (D.east);
```

To explain why, I first quote the manual (the second tutorial):

> It is now time for Hagen to learn about yet another way of specifying
>   edges: Using the `edge` path operation. This operation is very similar
>   to the `to` operation, but there is one important difference: Like a
>   node the edge generated by the `edge` operation is not part of the main
>   path, but is added only later. This may not seem very important, but
>   it has some nice consequences. For example, every edge can have its
>   own arrow tips and its own color and so on and, still, all the edges
>   can be given on the same path.

While I do not know the details, I guess this is the reason for the double arrow tips. You get one arrow tip from the main path, and another one for the `edge`, as that is added after the first path.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,arrows}   

\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!50!black!20, 
text width=2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2cm, minimum    width=4cm},
sblock/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!50!black!20, 
text width=2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2cm, minimum     width=2cm},
line/.style={draw, -latex'}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [block] at (6,3) (C) {C};  
   \node [sblock] at (1,2) (D) {D};   
   \path [thick] (C.west) edge [line,bend left] (D.east);
   \path [thick] (D.east) edge [line,bend left] (C.west);   


   \node [block] at (6,-1) (E) {E};  
   \node [sblock] at (1,-2) (F) {F};   
   \path [line,thick] (E.west) to[out=180,in=60] (F.east);
   \path [line,thick] (F.east) to[out=0,in=240] (E.west);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. What is the difference between edge and to?

Comment: @JPJanet I had a quick look in the manual and updated my answer a bit.

Comment: thank you for adding this explanation. There is so much going on behind the scenes in Tikz I really battle to make heads or tails of it!

Comment: @JPJanet One more thing: I forgot that you can use `to[bend left]` as well, which is perhaps easier than using `in=X,out=Y`.